# Start ActiveMQ from java with virtual consumer enabled (virtual consumer not working)

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I'm trying to start ActiveMQ from java enabling virtual destinations but I think I have the configuration wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Virtual Destination Interceptor
    VirtualTopic virtualTopic = new VirtualTopic();
    virtualTopic.setName("VirtualTopic.>");
    virtualTopic.setPrefix("Consumer.*.");
    VirtualDestinationInterceptor virtualDestinationInterceptor = new VirtualDestinationInterceptor();
    virtualDestinationInterceptor.setVirtualDestinations(new VirtualDestination[] {virtualTopic});

    // Create and Start the Broker
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.setDestinationInterceptors(new DestinationInterceptor[] {virtualDestinationInterceptor});
    broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.start();
}
```

This above should enable virtual destinations and allow me to send to a topic **VirtualTopic.myTopicName** and receive from **Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName**.
(Note this replaces the **activemq.xml** that I do not have.)

From my code I'm sending with:

```
jmsTopicTemplate.send("VirtualTopic.myTopicName", session -> session.createTextMessage(jmsEvent));
```

And receiving with:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName", containerFactory = "jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory")
```

But I'm not receiving the message.

Through jconsole I see that the message has been enqueued to **VirtualTopic.myTopicName** but **Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName** has a 0 count on dequeueing.

If changing the **@JmsListener** to:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "VirtualTopic.myTopicName", containerFactory = "jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory")
```

Then I'm receiving 5 messages (as I have 5 consumers).

Does anybody have any suggestion?
It really sounds like a configuration problem to me.

For completeness, those are my  **jmsTopicTemplate** and **jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory**

```
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTopicTemplate(@Qualifier("activeMQConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return jmsTemplate;
}

@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("activeMQConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("4-5");
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: This points to a real address     broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");. If you don't specify anything, (in spring boot project ) it should start JVM in memory broker at vm://localhost

Comment: I don't want an in memory broker. Actually My broker is started up as a different application. I really don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Ok, I see. Why are you trying to consume from "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName" ? when you publish it to "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName" ?

Comment: I never publish to "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName". I publish to "VirtualTopic.myTopicName" and expect to consume from "Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.myTopicName". That's how virtual destinations work :P.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! I got the error.

The error is in the **@JmsListenerContainerFactory**:

It should not anymore listen from a topic as Virtual Destinations are effectively Queues. I needed to remove **factory.setPubSubDomain(true);** and with the following it works.

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsTopicListenerContainerFactory(@Qualifier("activeMQConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("4-5");
    return factory;
}
```

Furthermore [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) documentation says that virtual destinations are active by default and it is true.

Therefore the code for starting ActiveMQ can be simplified to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.start();
}
```